# How to install IBM Secure Gateway client on Windows server with a internet access with Proxy

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

How can I enable the Secure Gateway client to use my proxy settings. The client uses npm bundled with the installation. I cannot pass proxy config as npm configuration. I tried setting http_proxy as system parameter but it seems not used. I see following in npm_debug file after installation.

```
323 error network connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.8.162:443
324 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
324 error network and is related to network connectivity.
324 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
324 error network
324 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
324 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
325 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Secure Gateway client installer does not currently support connecting through an external proxy due to limitations in the protocols supported by most proxies. However, the client connection process involves two outbound calls to known IPs which can be used to setup explicit firewall rules in secure environments. The IPs are available upon request via a Bluemix support ticket.